# Parameter and view naming collisions in Play/Scala templates

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to Play Framework and still trying to wrap my head around some things with the new Scala template engine.

Let's say I have the following package structure:

```
app/
app/controllers/Items.scala
app/models/Item.scala
app/views/layouts/page.scala.html
app/views/item/show.scala.html
app/views/item/details.scala.html  //partial
```

And this is my item/show template:

```
    @(item: Item, form: Form[Item])(implicit flash: Flash)
    @layout.page() {
        @*want to include details partial, wont work due to item param*@
        @item.details(item)
    }
```

Since including another template (e.g. including item/details above) is the exact same syntax as accessing a template parameter (e.g. item above), obviously this existing naming convention won't work without something changing.

I know I can rename my "app.views.item" package to "app.views.items", and rely on singular/plural forms to differentiate the view from the param name, but this does not seem like a very straightforward solution. Also what if I really want the parameter name to be the same as the view package?

One idea I have is to prepend all my views with an extra top level package:

```
 app/views/views/item/details.scala.html
```

So the include syntax would be  @views.item.details(), but again this is obviously a hack.

What is a good way to avoid this issue?  How can I better organize my code to avoid such naming collisions?

Most other template engines use operations like "include" or  "render" to specify a partial include. I don't mean to offend anyone here, but is the Play Scala template engine syntax so terse that it actually dictates the organization of code?

Comment: Maybe by using the full qualified name: `@views.item.details(item)`

Comment: Also I have noticed a similar issue with Controller and Model class names. In various sample applications I see model names such as "app.models.Item" and a controller names such as "app.controllers.Items".  With a package level import, it is now up to a new developer to figure out that "Item" is a model and "Items" is a controller. That works, an again it is terse, but I am concerned about the potential for confusion/poor readability.

Comment: @nico_ekito,  the fully qualified view name does not work for me.  I get a compilation error.  I have tried `@app.views.item.details(item)` as well as `@views.item.details(item)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: The proper fully qualified name that works is: `@views.html.item.details(item)`.

Comment: yeah, I always forget the .html ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 solutions:

#### First

Typpicaly for partial templates you should use `tags` as described [in the docs](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTemplateUseCases), where `app/views/tags` folder is a base:

file: `app/views/tags/product.scala.html`

in the templates (no initial import required in the parent view full syntax will allow you to avoid name-clash: `@tags.packageName.tagName()`):

```
<div id="container">
    @tags.product(item)
</div>
```

Of course in your case you can also use packages in the base folder

file: `app/views/tags/item/product.scala.html`

```
<div id="container">
    @tags.item.product(item)
</div>
```

I'm pretty sure that'll solve your problem.

#### Second

To avoid clash without changing package's name you can just rename the `item` in your view, also I recommend do not use a `form` name for the Form[T] as it can conflict with helpers:

```
@(existingItem: Item, existingItemForm: Form[Item])(implicit flash: Flash)
@layout.page() {
    @item.details(existingItem)
}
```

#### Third

If you'll fill your `Form[Item]` before passing to the view with given `Item` object, you don't need to pass both, as most probably you can get data from the form:

```
@(itemForm: Form[Item])(implicit flash: Flash)
@layout.page() {
    <div>Name of item is: @itemForm("name").value (this is a replacemnet for @@existingItem.name </div>
    @item.details(itemForm)
}
```

Of course in you product.scala.html you'll need to change the `@(item: Item)` param to `@(itemForm: Form[Item])`

Comment: Good call! It never occurred to me that since everything is a function, I can just consider an include to be a tag.   I was about to go with a convention like `app.views.item.includes` but I like the `app.views.tags.item` approach better.

Comment: I don't like (2), but I see your point on not using the parameter name "form" ... "itemForm" seems like a better call. (3) works, but assuming that I also want the the Item instance it doesn't solve my original problem.  I've already started refactoring code to use approach (1).